# React.isValidElement false negative

Tags: javascript, facebook, reactjs, mocha.js

Something weird is going on with the `react.js`  [Top-Level API](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.isvalidelement).

This is an excerpt of my `mocha` test:

```
it.only('should identify a ReactElement', function () {
  var component = ReactTestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
    <SomeComponent value={data.value} label={data.label} />
  );

  console.log(React.isValidElement(component));
  expect(React.isValidElement(component), 'to be truthy');
  expect(true, 'to be truthy');
});
```

Problem is, `isValidElement` returns false... which doesn't makes a lot of sense since I've just created the damn element.

Any clue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ReactTestUtils.renderIntoDocument(element)` takes in a `ReactElement` and returns a `ReactComponent`.

`React.isValidElement(element)` will only return true if `element` is a `ReactElement`.

In your case, `<SomeComponent value={data.value} label={data.label} />` is a `ReactElement` and `component` is a `ReactComponent`.

[Here's a guide](https://gist.github.com/sebmarkbage/fcb1b6ab493b0c77d589) on the React Terminology that you might find useful.

Comment: You're kind of right (see here https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/3479#issuecomment-84706205)

But since they deprecated `isValidComponent`, it is now unclear how can I identify those elements